# wxHaskell and Reactive-Banana staticText not Updating Size When Text Changes

Tags: user-interface, haskell, frp, wxhaskell, reactive-banana

I'm trying to build a simple UI as an exercise in learning wxHaskell and Reactive Banana, but I've run into a wall trying to solve a seemingly simple problem. Specifically, I'd like to resize the window to fit around a label when the label's text is updated, so that it always fits the text. I tried to accomplish this with `windowReLayoutMinimal`, but this unexpectedly caused both the window to fail to resize when the text overflowed, and the window to strobe between its original size and the new size when it was manually resized (i.e. stretching it with the handle in the corner). As far as I've been able to tell, the `StaticText` item's size is failing to update when the its text changes. Is there any way to force the item to recalculate its minimum size?
My code looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Graphics.UI.WX hiding (Event)
import Reactive.Banana
import Reactive.Banana.WX

main = start $ do
    mainWindow      <- frame [text := "Test"]
    inputText   <- textEntry mainWindow []
    outputText  <- staticText mainWindow []
    set mainWindow  [layout :=
                      margin 10 $
                      grid 10 10 [
                        [widget inputText, fill $ valignCenter $ widget outputText]
                      ]
                    ]
    let
        networkDescription :: forall t . Frameworks t => Moment t ()
        networkDescription = do
            inputTextEvStream <- eventText inputText
            let 
                currentInputText = stepper "" inputTextEvStream
            sink outputText [text :== currentInputText]
            reactimate $ windowReLayoutMinimal mainWindow <$ inputTextEvStream
    network <- compile networkDescription
    actuate network
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with wxHaskell to me. I don't know whether this helps, but you can try to set the layout again via `sink mainWindow [layout :== ...]` instead of using the `windowReLayoutMinimal` function.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus I already tried that, and while it does stop the flickering I see with `windowReLayoutMinimal`, it just makes the window consistently too small. I think the issue might be that wxHaskell is setting the `wxST_NO_AUTORESIZE` flag by default on static text items. I've been reading the wxHaskell library code to try to see if this is the case.

Comment: I have (I think) confirmed that the flags are being set correctly. So maybe the size reporting is screwed up? I'll have to look further.